# Multiple GitBooks inside main git repository?

Tags: git, gitbook

I'm planning to use [GitBook](https://www.gitbook.com/) for publishing user/system documentation for a large project. Documentation is organized as a collection of self-contained books, expected to be managed inside the main git repository like:

```
- root
  - sources
  - books
     - tutorial
       - assets
       - section-1
       - …
     - reference
       - …
```

Is it feasible to sync each book directory to an independent GitBook repository?

Bonus: is it feasible to have each GitBook repository automatically mirror the branching/tagging structure of the main repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sync each book directory to an independent GitBook repository?

You can if each book is in its own folder, declared as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**

> is it feasible to have each GitBook repository automatically mirror the branching/tagging structure of the main repository?

Not exactly: a submodule has no knowledge of the parent repo. But you can [configure a submodule to follow one of its branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309).

That allows, form the parent repo, to do a:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

That will fetch the latest from the branch followed by each submodules.